# Как вырезать иконки c изображения?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть API на nodejs в котором хранятся предметы и у каждого предмета есть своя иконка.

Иконки хранятся в одном файле формата DDS и размером 4096х4096

С форматом DDS у меня ничего не получилось, но конвертировав в png удалось разрезать, все это работает очень медленно.
Каждая иконка имеет разрешение 32х32. В файле 128 столбцов и 69 строк с иконками.

Хранить иконки нужно в base64 data image либо получать их по координатам из основного файла.

Возможно ли это нормально реализовать на nodejs? То, что у меня получилось, этим невозможно пользоваться...

Иконки в png:https://mega.nz/#!ClkWDCIR!LmKyUzekyVHPTBvnW68PXHru7_L8a6kr5SQU8aoS3No
Пример кода но он работает не так как нужно из-за свойства

> middleBoundaryMode: true

теряется первая иконка, возможно и другие. Без этого свойства после первой линии ошибка:

```
const imageToSlices = require('image-to-slices');
const Clipper = require('image-clipper');
const Canvas = require('canvas');

imageToSlices.configure({clipperOptions: {canvas: require('canvas')}});

let rows = [];
let cols = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 69; i++) rows[i] = 32*i;
for (let i = 1; i <= 128; i++) cols[i] = 32*i;


imageToSlices('iconlist_ivtrm.png', rows, cols, {
    saveToDir: './test', middleBoundaryMode: true
}, () => {console.log('the source image has been sliced!');});
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, смысл таких спрайтов - один раз загрузить на клиента и там закешировать. Не дергать АПИ и не вырезать каждый раз иконку. А потом на клиенте показывать только нужную иконку. Как здесь https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp